# How to get Notificationcenter data from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, remote-notifications

I'm working on an app that receives data from a remote notification, I'm trying to pass that data from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to my `ViewController` using `Notificationcenter` when opening the app through tapping on the notification using `launchOptions`. The problem is that the observer on my `viewDidAppear` is not getting any data.

This is my code on the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any] { 

             let nameSchool = remoteNotification["name_school" as! String]
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.nameSchool, object: nameSchool)

                }
    }
```

And the observer in the `viewDidAppear` method:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.nameSchool, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (nameSchool) in


            let schoolName = nameSchool.object as! String 

            self.messagePopup(message: "Data received")

        }
}
```

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on viewDidAppear of your view controller and in didFinishLaunching of your app delegate, can you confirm your viewDidAppear actually hit the breakpoint first?

Comment: The didFinishLaunching hits the breakpoint first. I set one at the end of the didFinishLaunching and another one at the very beginning of viewDidAppear. didFinishLaunching came first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application(,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) will be called before the viewDidAppear (as per your comment), then you will have to temporarily store the result you get from the function until your code can retrieve it later.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var remoteNotificationAtLaunch: [AnyHashable: Any]?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.remoteNotificationAtLaunch = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any]
    }

    ...
}
```

Obviously keep the part you already have in your AppDelegate that generates the post to NotificationCenter when a remote notification is received.  Then in your view controller, update your viewDidAppear...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    observeNotifications()
    checkForNotificationAtLaunch()
}

private func observeNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.nameSchool, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (nameSchool) in
        let schoolName = nameSchool.object as! String
        self.processNotification(schoolName: schoolName)
    }
}

private func checkForNotificationAtLaunch() {
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        if let notificationAtLaunch = appDelegate.remoteNotificationAtLaunch,
            let schoolName = notificationAtLaunch["name_school"] as? String {
            processNotification(schoolName: schoolName)
        }
    }
}

private func processNotification(schoolName: String) {
    self.messagePopup(message: "data received")
    // do something with schoolName....
}
```

Comment: And that's it! I finally got it working. I was able to solve the notification issue on my app thanks to you. Thank you so so much :)